# how to add drop shadow while scrolling floating header in listview android(like Gmail)

Tags: android, listview

I am using a https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView ,and I have customised rows in the listviews but I am unable to add dropshadow to header when floating over childviews and when it is back in position the dropshadow should disappear .How can I make that feature work with the current code.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

SampleActivity

```
package com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.FloatingGroupExpandableListView;
import com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.WrapperExpandableListAdapter;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);

        final FloatingGroupExpandableListView list = (FloatingGroupExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_header, list, false);
        list.addHeaderView(header);

        final View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_footer, list, false);
        footer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        list.addFooterView(footer);

        // Even though the child divider has already been set on the layout file, we have to set it again here
        // This prevents a bug where the background turns to the color of the child divider when the list is expanded
        list.setChildDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));

        final SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(this);
        final WrapperExpandableListAdapter wrapperAdapter = new WrapperExpandableListAdapter(adapter);
        list.setAdapter(wrapperAdapter);

        for(int i = 0; i < wrapperAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            list.expandGroup(i);
        }

        list.setOnScrollFloatingGroupListener(new FloatingGroupExpandableListView.OnScrollFloatingGroupListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollFloatingGroupListener(View floatingGroupView, int scrollY) {
                float interpolation = - scrollY / (float) floatingGroupView.getHeight();

                // Changing from RGB(162,201,85) to RGB(255,255,255)
                final int greenToWhiteRed = (int) (162 + 93 * interpolation);
                final int greenToWhiteGreen = (int) (201 + 54 * interpolation);
                final int greenToWhiteBlue = (int) (85 + 170 * interpolation);
                final int greenToWhiteColor = Color.argb(255, greenToWhiteRed, greenToWhiteGreen, greenToWhiteBlue);

                // Changing from RGB(255,255,255) to RGB(0,0,0)
                final int whiteToBlackRed = (int) (255 - 255 * interpolation);
                final int whiteToBlackGreen = (int) (255 - 255 * interpolation);
                final int whiteToBlackBlue = (int) (255 - 255 * interpolation);
                final int whiteToBlackColor = Color.argb(255, whiteToBlackRed, whiteToBlackGreen, whiteToBlackBlue);

                final ImageView image = (ImageView) floatingGroupView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_item_image);
                image.setBackgroundColor(greenToWhiteColor);

                final Drawable imageDrawable = image.getDrawable().mutate();
                imageDrawable.setColorFilter(whiteToBlackColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                final View background = floatingGroupView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_item_background);
                background.setBackgroundColor(greenToWhiteColor);

                final TextView text = (TextView) floatingGroupView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_item_text);
                text.setTextColor(whiteToBlackColor);

                final ImageView expanded = (ImageView) floatingGroupView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_expanded_image);
                final Drawable expandedDrawable = expanded.getDrawable().mutate();
                expandedDrawable.setColorFilter(whiteToBlackColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SampleAdapter

```
package com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private final String[] mGroups = {
            "Cupcake",
            "Donut",
            "Eclair",
            "Froyo",
            "Gingerbread",
            "Honeycomb",
            "Ice Cream Sandwich",
            "Jelly Bean",
            "KitKat"
    };

    private final int[] mGroupDrawables = {
            R.drawable.cupcake,
            R.drawable.donut,
            R.drawable.eclair,
            R.drawable.froyo,
            R.drawable.gingerbread,
            R.drawable.honeycomb,
            R.drawable.ice_cream_sandwich,
            R.drawable.jelly_bean,
            R.drawable.kitkat
    };

    private final String[][] mChilds = {
            {"1.5"},
            {"1.6"},
            {"2.0","2.0.1","2.1"},
            {"2.2","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.3"},
            {"2.3","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.3.4","2.3.5","2.3.6","2.3.7"},
            {"3.0","3.1","3.2","3.2.1","3.2.2","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.2.5","3.2.6"},
            {"4.0", "4.0.1", "4.0.2", "4.0.3", "4.0.4"},
            {"4.1", "4.1.1", "4.1.2", "4.2", "4.2.1", "4.2.2", "4.3", "4.3.1"},
            {"4.4"}
    };

    private final String[][] mChilds2 = {
            {"1.5"},
            {"1.6"},
            {"2.0","2.0.1","2.1"},
            {"2.2","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.3"},
            {"2.3","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.3.4","2.3.5","2.3.6","2.3.7"},
            {"3.0","3.1","3.2","3.2.1","3.2.2","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.2.5","3.2.6"},
            {"4.0", "4.0.1", "4.0.2", "4.0.3", "4.0.4"},
            {"4.1", "4.1.1", "4.1.2", "4.2", "4.2.1", "4.2.2", "4.3", "4.3.1"},
            {"4.4"}
    };

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_group_item, parent, false);
        }

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_item_image);
        image.setImageResource(mGroupDrawables[groupPosition]);

        final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_item_text);
        text.setText(mGroups[groupPosition]);

        final ImageView expandedImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_group_expanded_image);
        final int resId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.minus : R.drawable.plus;
        expandedImage.setImageResource(resId);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mChilds[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity_list_child_item, parent, false);
        }

        final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_activity_list_child_item_text);
        text.setText(mChilds[groupPosition][childPosition]);

        final TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text2.setText(mChilds2[groupPosition][childPosition]);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Group_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample_activity_list_group_item_image"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#FFA2C955"
        android:padding="3dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample_activity_list_group_item_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFA2C955"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sample_activity_list_group_item_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sample_activity_list_group_expanded_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

sample_Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFEDEDED"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.FloatingGroupExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/sample_activity_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:childDivider="#FF000000"
        android:divider="#FF000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```